# time on MBP doesnot update

Tags: mac

I am using MBP running yosemite(10.10.1) retina 15inch mid 2014, it is not showing correct time. It just started time from the time i closed the lid. even why do auto synch with time server or apple time server. it doesn't.

Comment: Can you please run `sudo grep ntpd /var/log/system.log` (or, if this doesn't show anything, `sudo zgrep ntpd /var/log/system.log*`, `cat /etc/ntp.conf` and `ps aux|grep  ntp` and then use the **edit** link below the question to add the output to the post? A screenshot showing the Preferences window for Time settings would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this problem on my work laptop occasionally. By looking at the system log in Console I found that SystemUIServer had hung. Going into Activity Monitor showed that SystemUIServer was not responding & force quitting the process instantly fixed the issue for me and my menu bar clock began keeping the correct time again.
See if that works for you.